Text wrap does not respect aspect ratio
I am trying to create a testimonial. There is a testimonial container that contains three direct child divs: profile-image, name, and feedback. The testimonial div is flexbox, and its direction is column. I have set flex-grow: 1 for the feedback to consume all the space available of the parent div (testimonial container).
I wanted the feedback divs to be wrapped, and overflow should be handled with ellipsis while preserving the aspect ratio of the parent div. But this is not working. Instead, the div height grows whenever the moment text overflow happens.


body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.testimonial-container {
  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio: 4/5;
  margin: 2px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.testimonial-container .profile-image {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonial-container .profile-image img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.testimonial-container .name {
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonial-container .feedback {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background-color: rgb(166, 199, 170);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Testimonials</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="testimonial-container">
    <div class="profile-image ">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529665253569-6d01c0eaf7b6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
    </div>
    <div class="name text-center mt-3 fw-bolder">Name</div>
    <div class="feedback">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi iure, dicta ratione vero doloribus facere aspernatur laborum, illum at mollitia quia corrupti quidem sequi obcaecati animi aut. Adipisci fugiat, quod earum iusto quae, omnis odio labore ex laudantium consequatur dolor! Quod maiores quidem numquam ex ab ratione omnis rem praesentium, debitis placeat tenetur iusto sapiente commodi vitae unde mollitia quae ea, facilis saepe provident ipsum laboriosam similique ipsa? Aliquam et, voluptates neque quo, laboriosam alias nemo molestias fugiat suscipit obcaecati nulla nam omnis quam perferendis dolorum cupiditate provident dolore! Quo nemo id accusantium natus. Voluptate harum, ratione id totam quas eum amet nostrum alias obcaecati officiis qui perspiciatis itaque ullam adipisci repellat veniam eius ipsam vitae beatae eaque eligendi, omnis, deleniti cumque laboriosam! Eius maxime dicta quod ex libero natus sit quam totam voluptate, nam eligendi! Quasi ullam numquam ut doloribus quis ipsam, perferendis tempora ducimus natus cumque facilis deserunt.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Using just HTML/CSS I don't think you can get a totally general solution, especially if you want ellipsis. Have you considered signally to the user that there is more by some other method - either of course a scroll bar or, more subtly perhaps, by fading out the bottom line or two that are visible so they know there is more?

Fading out seems to be a good idea. But not sure how to do that. Also what If there is no more lines then what will happen?

text-overflow is only intended for one-line text. Nowadays you can use these parameters:
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-line-clamp: 6;

In this case you need to define a value for -webkit-line-clamp, i.e. the number of lines. With the aspect ratio, font-size, image size etc. in your example, 6 would be a value that works, but you can of course change it to whatever fits your need, using trial and error for finding out:


body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.testimonial-container {
  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio: 5/4;
  margin: 2px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.testimonial-container .profile-image {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonial-container .profile-image img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.testimonial-container .name {
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonial-container .feedback {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(166, 199, 170);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Testimonials</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="testimonial-container">
    <div class="profile-image ">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529665253569-6d01c0eaf7b6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
    </div>
    <div class="name text-center mt-3 fw-bolder">Name</div>
    <div class="feedback">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi iure, dicta ratione vero doloribus facere aspernatur laborum, illum at mollitia quia corrupti quidem sequi obcaecati animi aut. Adipisci fugiat, quod earum iusto quae, omnis odio labore ex laudantium consequatur dolor! Quod maiores quidem numquam ex ab ratione omnis rem praesentium, debitis placeat tenetur iusto sapiente commodi vitae unde mollitia quae ea, facilis saepe provident ipsum laboriosam similique ipsa? Aliquam et, voluptates neque quo, laboriosam alias nemo molestias fugiat suscipit obcaecati nulla nam omnis quam perferendis dolorum cupiditate provident dolore! Quo nemo id accusantium natus. Voluptate harum, ratione id totam quas eum amet nostrum alias obcaecati officiis qui perspiciatis itaque ullam adipisci repellat veniam eius ipsam vitae beatae eaque eligendi, omnis, deleniti cumque laboriosam! Eius maxime dicta quod ex libero natus sit quam totam voluptate, nam eligendi! Quasi ullam numquam ut doloribus quis ipsam, perferendis tempora ducimus natus cumque facilis deserunt.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



P.S.: Check here for browser compatibility - looks good: https://caniuse.com/?search=webkit-line-clamp

Overflow is not handled with ellipsis.

II think you missed overflow:hidden for the feeback.

I have removed aspect ratio and added below code for .testimonial-container .feedback.
display: -webkit-box;
max-width: 100%;
-webkit-line-clamp: 6;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;

Please check the browser support for these properties.


body{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        .testimonial-container{
            width: 300px;  
            margin: 2px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .testimonial-container .profile-image{
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .testimonial-container .profile-image img{
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
            clip-path: circle(50%);
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        .testimonial-container .name{
            color: orange;
        text-align: center;
        }

        .testimonial-container .feedback{
            flex-basis: 1;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(166, 199, 170);
            
            display: -webkit-box;
            max-width: 100%;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            overflow: hidden;
            }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testimonials</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="testimonial-container">
        <div class="profile-image ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529665253569-6d01c0eaf7b6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
        </div>
        <div class="name text-center mt-3 fw-bolder">Name</div>
        <div class="feedback">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi iure, dicta ratione vero doloribus facere aspernatur laborum, illum at mollitia quia corrupti quidem sequi obcaecati animi aut. Adipisci fugiat, quod earum iusto quae, omnis odio labore ex laudantium consequatur dolor! Quod maiores quidem numquam ex ab ratione omnis rem praesentium, debitis placeat tenetur iusto sapiente commodi vitae unde mollitia quae ea, facilis saepe provident ipsum laboriosam similique ipsa? Aliquam et, voluptates neque quo, laboriosam alias nemo molestias fugiat suscipit obcaecati nulla nam omnis quam perferendis dolorum cupiditate provident dolore! Quo nemo id accusantium natus. Voluptate harum, ratione id totam quas eum amet nostrum alias obcaecati officiis qui perspiciatis itaque ullam adipisci repellat veniam eius ipsam vitae beatae eaque eligendi, omnis, deleniti cumque laboriosam! Eius maxime dicta quod ex libero natus sit quam totam voluptate, nam eligendi! Quasi ullam numquam ut doloribus quis ipsam, perferendis tempora ducimus natus cumque facilis deserunt.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




How do you know that 6 lines is what is needed?

I don't know. That's assumption.  That could be changed.
